# Do all melee attacks deal the same amount of damage?

Tags: overwatch

I'm still a little unsure on this one.  Are all melee attacks from all heroes (by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> (default)) identical, in damage, hitbox, and range? Or are some melee attacks more damaging than others, or are there others that have more range than others?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With one exception, all quick melee attacks performed with the <kbd>V</kbd> key deal 30 damage and have the same hitbox. When playing as Brigitte, pressing <kbd>V</kbd> will swing her main weapon instead.

Some melee attacks, however, are their own weapons: Reinhardt's hammer deals 75 damage, Torbjorn's hammer deals 55 damage, Brigitte's flail deals 35 damage, Winston's attacks during Primal Rage deal 40 damage, and Genji's Dragonblade deals 120 damage.

Comment: Good answer apart from including 2 weapons and 2 ultimates ...

Comment: @ИвоНедев Which are also melee attacks and I decided to include for completion's sake, even if not explicitly mentioned in the question.

Comment: To confirm: if you hit the quick melee button as Reinhardt, that will still do 30 damage, even though you're technically hitting them with the hammer, correct?

Comment: @DCShannon I'm fairly sure Reinhardt has no quick melee. Same with all of the other melee weapons.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Reinhardt has no quick melee, and Torbjorn can't quick melee while his hammer is out: http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_Melee

Comment: Okay so little Torbjorn hits as hard as huge Reinhardt? That huge rocket propelled anvil thrown sideways with all of Reinhardt's strength doesn't do more damage than a utility hammer barely swung slightly forward by Torbjorn? LOL...the more you know...